# How do I update a link with a full directory path with jQuery URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function thats purpose is to update links in HTML loaded into the page via jQuery.get(). The backend application has thousands of links that can't readily be updated to include full paths, and so when converting to a single-page application many links are relative to /, when they need to include a full path.

I've read several questions here about converting from relative to absolute paths and finding the absolute path, but they don't quite fit what I'm trying to do, and my understanding of Javascript and jQuery is still weak enough that I don't know how to search for answers beyond this sticking point.

Here's my function:

```
// handle modifying links, and attaching events
// href - The URL of the age that was loaded that triggered the handler callback
// target = left or right (must be ID, as # will be appended
var handler = function (data, href, target) {
  // Insert data into div
  $( '#' + target ).html(data);

  // Convert relative URLs in #right to include directory
  var base_path = URI(href).directory();

  $('#right a:uri(is: relative)').attr('href', base_path+'/'+$(this).href);
};
```

This successfully finds and adds the base_path (it gets it from the href variable being passed into the function), but I can't figure out how to get the original filename and query string in there. I get undefined...so I obviously don't understand '$(this)' or .href. I tried a number of other options for getting this data, but they either result in an error or undefined value...again, indicating I have no idea what I'm doing. Googling "this" is hard.

I also tried using $(this).attr('href'), but the result is the same...undefined.

In short: when I'm updating a URI attr how do I figure out the originally selected href within the attr update and put it into the new URI?

Note I'm using jQuery and this jQuery URI library: http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/jquery-uri-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured this out with a whole bunch more googling. The function that works for what I needed is:

```
var handler = function (data, href, target) {
  // Insert data into div
  $( '#' + target ).html(data);

  console.log("href = ", href);
  // Convert relative URLs in #right to include directory
  var base_path = URI(href).directory();
  //var base_path = uri.directory() + '/';
  console.log(base_path);
  $('#right a:uri(is: relative)').each(function() {
    var cur_href = $(this).attr("href");
    $(this).attr("href", base_path+"/"+cur_href);
  });
};
```

The change is to use .each to allow an anonymous function to do the work on each relative link.